# Does NetChain have a "Distribution" property like PredictorFunction?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

`PredictorFunction` has an incredibly useful "Distribution" property. In the past, this has helped me filter out bad predictions, like this:

```
approxError[input_]:=StandardDeviation[myPredictorFunction[input, "Distribution"]]
```

I have a `NetChain` model that I've trained, but I don't know how to calculate how confident the model is in its predictions. Is there a similar function or property I could use?